# What controls the Python search path, and how?

Tags: ros, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my shell I first activate a Python virtual environment and then the Catkin workspace which results in this `sys.path`, which searches for Python modules in this order.

```
[
    '/home/user/project/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages',
    '/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages',
    '/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python37.zip',
    '/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.7',
    '/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7',
    '/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
    '/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages'
]
```

Yet when I run `roslaunch` from this shell, which in turn executes a Python node, this is the `sys.path` it sees. **My virtual environment is no longer active.**

```
[
    '/home/user/project/src/pkg/src',
    '/home/user/project/devel/.private/pkg/lib/pkg',
    '/home/user/project/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages',
    '/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python37.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
    '/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages'
]
```

I would expect it to add the first two entries (so that the ROS package's own Python modules take priority), but keep the rest which include my `.venv` directories.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399373/what-controls-the-python-search-path,-and-how?/) by [rgov](https://answers.ros.org/users/45623/rgov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2022-04-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rgov](https://answers.ros.org/users/45623/rgov/) on 2022-04-21**:
It appears that it is due to the Python interpreter `/usr/bin/python3` being executed instead of `/home/user/project/.venv/bin/python3` even though the shebang line is `#!/usr/bin/env python3` and the `PATH` (as the node sees it) should prioritize the one from my virtual environment.

**Comment by [rgov](https://answers.ros.org/users/45623/rgov/) on 2022-04-21**:
When `roslaunch` calls `execve()` to run my node, it is executing (via some symlinks) `/home/user/project/devel/.private/pkg/lib/pkg/node` which is a script that goes:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# generated from catkin/cmake/template/script.py.in
```

Which rather than just execute the program as any other executable, reads the entire thing and then executes it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Basically, my nodes were being launched with a different `python3` executable than I expected.

This is because `roslaunch` *actually* launches a trampoline script, based on [this template](https://github.com/ros/catkin/blob/noetic-devel/cmake/templates/script.py.in), that provides a different shebang line which is fixed **at build time**.

(Aside: This seems like very unusual behavior from Catkin. Why not just write out a file with `#!/whatever/python3 pathtofile.py` instead of this? Why the circuitousness?)

To get the right shebang line in this trampoline, the virtual environment needs to be active while building.

---

Originally posted by [rgov](https://answers.ros.org/users/45623/rgov/) with karma: 130 on 2022-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1